# SAS differences in outcome between sql and proc means

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I want to have a weighted average of some variable in a macro variable. My var is *zindi&aa* and my weight is *wprm&aa*

I am trying to make sense of two ways of doing it :

**one with a proc sql**

```
proc sql noprint;
    select mean(zindi&aa. * wprm&aa.)/sum(wprm&aa.) into :Mean_zindi_aa
    from Panel(where=(annee&ap.<="&nais18" ));
quit;
```

it yields me an average of **0.77**

**one with proc means**

```
proc means data=Panel(where=(annee&ap.<="&nais18" )); 
    var zindi&ap. ;
    weight wprm&ap ;
    output out=mean_zindi&ap mean=moy&ap;
run;
```

and then a data _null_ part

which yields an average of around **20200** that seems to be the correct one

so my question is

- what  I am missing with the proc sql so that it does give an absurd result ?
- is there a better way to obtain my macro variable **&mean_zindi_aa**

Comment: A tip for future reference.. you can help yourself debug issues like this simply by breaking out the formula into different variables, and working on a limited number of observations where it is possible to calculate the answer by hand.  You would have picked up this issue pretty quickly that way.

Comment: yes I am kind of embarassed. I am just starting to know how to use sql, so I wrongly assumed it was a problem of the way I used it instead of checking the formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    proc sql noprint;
    select sum(zindi&aa. * wprm&aa.)/sum(wprm&aa.) into :Mean_zindi_aa
    from Panel(where=(annee&ap.<="&nais18" ));
    quit;
```

Try this. Looks like you are trying to do a mean on (zindi&aa. * wprm&aa.). If you need the weighted average the above should work. because weighted average =  sum(weight*variable)/sum(weights)

Answer (score 1):

Change your PROC SQL to:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select SUM(zindi&aa. * wprm&aa.)/sum(wprm&aa.) into :Mean_zindi_aa
    from Panel(where=(annee&ap.<="&nais18" ));
quit;
```

You need to SUM the product, not take the MEAN.